# How to programmatically enable Windows Search component in Windows 7?

Tags: search, windows-7

I've found many references on how to manually enable the Windows Search component, e.g.:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10246/how-to-disable-search-in-windows-7/

But the question remains: how to automate this code-wise?